# How to change the text color of the material radio button

Tags: css, angular, material-ui

I need your help. I have a small piece of code. I use Material UI together with Angular. I have a group with a radio button. The fact is that the text in the radio button does not change, although I set the scss value to change to this color: # 262D34.

```
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
   <mat-radio-button value="1" class="radio_button">
     Roman Dyshko
   </mat-radio-button>
   <mat-radio-button value="2" class="radio_button">
     Roman Dyshko
   </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>

.radio_button {
   font-family: 'Work Sans', serif;
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: 400;
   font-size: 14px;
   line-height: 150%;
   text-decoration-line: underline;
   color: #556EE6;
}

mat-radio-group mat-radio-button .radio_button {
  color: #556EE6;
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with you. Do not panic :p. To override the default color of Angular Material components you have to force that style rule by adding !important after putting ::ng-deep infront of the class names.

Comment: I don't think using `!important` is totally necessary, at least, personally talking. I've only had problems in a few components, and had to force it. But in general, it won't be a problem @Walid

Comment: If my answer doesn't help you, try creating a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) with a minimal reproduction. I'll gladly take a look at it. You're not the only one having problems with this, so it's a good question. I removed the part where you were doubting yourself to keep it short for later visitors. ;) Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You must use `::ng-deep` if you want to have fully access to the styling of those components. Like this:

```
::ng-deep mat-radio-group mat-radio-button .radio_button {
  color: #556EE6;
}
```

Above code would work generally, in case you want to go through a component styling.

### Updated answer

In case you want to restyle your radio buttons, it should be something like this:

```
::ng-deep
  .mat-radio-button.mat-accent.mat-radio-checked
  .mat-radio-outer-circle {
  border-color: blue; /*change radio button color when selected*/
}

::ng-deep .mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-inner-circle {
  background-color: red; /*change radio button inner circle color */
}

::ng-deep .mat-radio-outer-circle {
  border: 1px solid black; /*change radio button not checked border */
}

::ng-deep .mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-ripple .mat-ripple-element {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) !important; /* change click effect color */
}
```

Note: I used `!important`, because as said, only in a few cases you must use force the style to change.

Comment: Sorry, but it didin't help

Comment: @Defender I already know why it doesn't work, I will update my question shortly. I am trying to make it full functional!

Comment: @Defender check the answer now, it should be working (I tested it myself)

Comment: I know that, but when you want a specific style, I believe you have to use it @H3AR7B3A7.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the default style with `::ng-deep`. It is deprecated  feature and it might change the color application wide. So use with caution like this.

```
::ng-deep mat-radio-group mat-radio-button .radio_button {
  color: #556EE6 !important; //<--- not necessary but needed in some cases
}
```

You need to add `!important` (in some cases) and kill your terminal if you have an active one. Re-compile the app again it should solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry, but it didin't help. The color of text radio button is still gray...

Comment: Then the way you take the class names from the DOM is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

### Material Radio Buttons

#### Text Color

Angular's API states that the **ng-deep** psuedo-class is **deprecated** and completely disables view-encapsulation for that rule.

If we use it without the :host pseudo-class, it will make the style-rule global, not a good thing. Which is what Angular will suggest you to do if there is no other way. (There is not atm.)

You can just use this in `styles.scss`, if you are sure you want them to bee applied globally.

```css
.mat-radio-button {
  color: pink;
}
```

Or if you want to use a color from your palette:

```css
.mat-radio-button {
  color: mat.get-color-from-palette($primary-light, 400);
}
```

If however you want it applied just to a specific radio-button in `some.component.scss`, you can use `::ng-deep`, but make sure to use the `:host` pseudo class to prevent the rule from bleeding out of the component:

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-radio-button {
  color: #556EE6;
}
```

*In short, you just need to know the right class names to override. In some cases like the **ripple**, the `!important` is needed to override the default.*

#### What about !important ?

Some people also like to override the ripple to be in a secondary or off-color. So I'll use that as an example:

```css
.mat-radio-ripple .mat-ripple-element {
  background-color: mat.get-color-from-palette(
    $accent-palette,
    A400
  ) !important;
}
```

*For this, or other styles you have already overwritten in your `styles.scss`, you do need to add `!important`.*

#### Only Select Tags

Another example for when you want only select groups/radio-buttons to gain the styling. You can add your own class to it as an extra selector.

Template:

```html
<li>
  <mat-radio-group
    class="pink"
    aria-label="Select an option"
    formControlName="gender"
  >
    <mat-radio-button color="primary" value="male">Male</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button value="female">Female</mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
</li>
```

Css:

```
.pink .mat-radio-button {
  color: pink;
}
```

Or for just one of the radio buttons:

```html
<div class="pink">
  <mat-radio-button value="female">Female</mat-radio-button>
</div>
```

#### Dynamically Add them on a Condition

Or here's another example if you want a style to be applied dynamically.

Template:

```html
<div [ngClass]"getClass()">
  <mat-radio-button value="female">Female</mat-radio-button>
</div>
```

Script:

```js
getClass(event: Event) {
  if(/* Your conditions */)
    return ['pink']
  return []
}
```

#### Stackblitz

Here's a [Material Form Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-iysjzg?file=src/app/app.component.ts) on my Stackblitz account I edited to show everything you can find above (and more), including a Matial Theme etc. In it I'm overriding the mat-radio-button globally in `styles.scss` and also in `app.component.scss`.

Comment: i don't want to change my cirlce color, i want to change text  and i have a radio button, not simple button

Comment: All these examples are about mat-radio-button, what are you talking about?

Comment: The circle color was an example I added because ppl kept talking about having to add !important, but you don't. You do on ripple though. You couldn't get a better more complete answer than this...